# How to use a listbox.selecteditem to continue work with an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, listbox, hashtable

For a small project of mine, I try to build a small Vocabulary trainer. I am using arrays, to store the vocabulary and the translation.
I have a listbox, where I can choose a specific topic which looks like this:

```
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Weekdays')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Months')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Numbers 1-10')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Numbers 10-20')
```

So as soon as I have my listbox, I can choose from the above 4 topics.
The issue I am fighting with is, how do I tell the code, that for example
the before chosen Weekdays, shall go through the array called $weekdays?

I played around with Hashtables to convert weekdays into $weekdays

```
$Vocabulary = @{Weekdays = $Weekdays; Months = $Months; Numbers = $Numbers}
```

But then I face different problems, not being able to dissolve the code on such way, that I get the first word out of the array as below:

```
$Weekdays = 'Montag','Dienstag','Mittwoch'
$weekdays_Answer = 'Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'
$Months = 'Januar','Februar','März','April','Mai','Juni'
$Months_Answer = 'January','February','March','April','May','June'
```

So my question is, what do I have to do, that when I pick 'Weekdays'from the listbox, that with this output, I receive the arrayname '$Weekdays', so I can continue to work from there?

I tried several approaches like:

```
$Vocabulary[$listbox.SelectedItems]

$test=$listbox.SelectedItems

$Vocabulary['weekdays'][0]

$Vocabularytopic = '$'+$listbox.selecteditem

$($TopicSelection.Values)[$Script:CounterVocabulary]
```

But so far no success, because I am not sure, how to convert the result from the listbox into an array. The closest I got was with:

```
$Vocabulary['weekdays'][0]
```

but here I failed by exchanging 'weekdays' with $listbox.selecteditems. Maybe you are able to figure this one out?

The reason for having two separate arrays is, that I first question the foreign word and then through a click onto a button, show the answer.

Open for any suggestions and other approaches

Many thanx,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution, should anyone have similar difficulties.

```
$vocabulary.($listbox.text)[0]
```

Gives me the result 'Montag' I was searching for.